# Cómo puedo usar javascript solo en una dimensión específica

Tags: javascript

Quiero saber cómo puedo usar las **media queries** pero en **javascript** para poner en funcionamiento un codigo pero una dimensión específica

```js
// ACTIVAR ESTE SCRIPT EN UNA DIMENSIÓN DE 700PX DE ANCHO
function texto() {
var edit = "Estás en un movil";
document.getElementById("caja").innerHTML = edit;
}
```

```css
.caja{
color: #fff;
background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="caja" class="caja">Estás en una pc</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer con el evento [onresize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) para calcular el ancho y alto de la pantalla, de esta manera al ser menor a 700px aparecerá el texto que le indique que se encuentra en un móvil, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
let edit = "Estás en un movil";

window.onresize = function(event) {

    if(innerWidth < 700){
    document.getElementById("caja").innerHTML = edit;
    }else{
    document.getElementById("caja").innerHTML = 'Estás en una pc';
    }
};
```

```css
.caja{
color: #fff;
background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="caja" class="caja">Estás en una pc</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `matchMedia` este objeto te permite hacer media queries css nativas en javascript

adjunto ejemplo:

```
if(matchMedia("(min-width: 1200px)").matches){
   console.log("tu probablemente estas en un ordenador de escritorio")
}
```

Debes escribir la media querie como si estuvieses en css, el atributo matches devolvera true o false dependiendo de si la media querie resulto ser verdadera o no
y pim pam pum ahi esta tu media querie en javascript